# when ad add code on my file as it is on video i get error "./src/app/app.module.ts Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/http'"

Tags: angular, angular2-http

i am new in angular world. i trying to learn this framework but it is so HARD!... so in my first example i got error:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule, 
    FormsModule, 
    HttpModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

and the error is :

> Failed to compile.
>
> ./src/app/app.module.ts
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/http' in 'C:\Hosts\ng4tutorial\src\app'

what I missed ..?

Comment: No shortage of docs on how to use Http in Angular: https://angular.io/guide/http

Comment: import `HttpClientModule `   like `import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http'`

Comment: Also if you are brand new I suggest to start with lot simpler stuff first.

Comment: robert can you advise me which video course is good for me ?

Comment: @გენომუმლაძე Try [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CusfUmB6mkY&list=PL6n9fhu94yhWNJaDgh0mfae_9xoQ4E_Zj)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your angular : `ng --version`

Please note that **Http** was deprecated in the version 4.3 of Angular.

If you have a newer version i recommend to you to use  the new Api : **HttpClient**  which came with many updates and support for progress events, json deserialization by default, Interceptors and many other great features.

See how to use it and more here https://angular.io/guide/http